# menu_icon not displaying

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post_type created in wordpress admin control panel.
all is working just fine except the menu_icon

```
'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/my_menu_icon.png',
```

it's not loading at all...
the image file is located in my_theme/images

is there a code instead to use the template directory for the menu_icon? or do i need to save the image file somewhere else?

I have no clue..

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what is wrong.

Never name you theme with a space (%20). As the local host wont recognize it within the functions.php when using the template directory or stylesheet uri.

So both code will work for the menu icon display.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/images/my_menu_icon.png',
```

Comment: Can it be because i am still on the localhost i have no access to the wp-content/themes/nameoftheme/images/my_menu_icon.png ??

Comment: Even on localhost you should have access to the file. I work localhost all the time and i have access to everything all the time.

Comment: wierd... the functions.php is in my template folder and yet if type the full path in at the localhost, i have no access to the png. all other things works on the localhost except the menu-icon... now i have no clue where to look...